# Is "destroying passions" a good thing in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context

All passions have a phase when they are merely disastrous, in which they draw their victims down by weight of stupidity – and a later, very much later one in which they marry the spirit, ‘spiritualize’ themselves. In former times, because of the stupidity of passion, people waged war on passion itself: they plotted to destroy it ... Destroying the passions and desires merely in order to avoid their stupidity and the disagreeable consequences of their stupidity seems to us nowadays to be itself simply an acute form of stupidity. We no longer marvel at dentists who pull out teeth to stop them hurting.

Comment: Not according to the paragraph, which says that destroying passions to avoid stupidity, is itself stupid.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh in that case is the last sentence satirical?

Comment: I don't think so. It is saying that we now know better ways to deal with tooth ache than removing the tooth. It's an analogy.

Comment: This looks like a fragment of one particular translation of Nietzsche's treatise [*Morality as Anti-Nature*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3cYUDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA21&dq=%22the+passions+and+desires+merely+in+order+to+avoid%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiP__u6jN_sAhWRecAKHeSbB4sQ6AEwAHoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22the%20passions%20and%20desires%20merely%20in%20order%20to%20avoid%22&f=false) in *Twilight of the Idols*. So regardless of what any native Anglophones *today* might think it means, the best way to find out would be to consult the original German text to see what ***he*** meant.

Comment: @WeatherVane Now I got it. Thank you~

Comment: @FumbleFingers Will do. Thank You!